# Impact of existing indexes on performance of COPY FROM

Tags: postgresql, indexing, sqlbulkcopy

After reading the [PostgreSQL reference doc on `COPY`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/sql-copy.html), I did not find how `COPY` deals with indexes. What exactly happens when COPYing data from a file into a table when the table already has indexes. I wonder if these indexes will be destroyed automatically first and then re-created after the loading or not?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is another page in the manual called [**Populating a Database**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/populate.html#POPULATE-COPY-FROM) that deals with that question. Its advice:

> If you are loading a freshly created table, the fastest method is to
>   create the table, bulk load the table's data using `COPY`, then create
>   any indexes needed for the table. Creating an index on pre-existing
>   data is quicker than updating it incrementally as each row is loaded.

All clear, right? But read the page, there's probably more for you.

Answer (score 3):

COPY currently does nothing special with indexes.

If you must insert into an indexed table, there is not much of a performance difference between COPY and a batched INSERT.

So if you can't drop the indexes then just use whichever command is most convenient given the current format of the data.

Comment: does indexes will be update to take into account the newly added rows ?

Comment: @FopaLéonConstantin Yes, of course they do. That's why it's slower.